# Cannot create table due to 'invalid datatype.' Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, ddl

So, I'm simply creating a table called `Flight`. Here's the syntax:

[image]

Everything looks fine. I can't figure out what it is. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: don't use date as  column name .. try date_1  DATE not null,

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: There is no `TIME` data type in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following link for the [Oracle Built-in Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

You can use `TIMESTAMP` datatype instead of `TIME` as you declared in your `CREATE` statement.

Since `DATE` is a reserved keyword for `DATE` datatype, you should opt not to use it as your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle date datatypes include the time so you might not need the date field at all.  You could have departureDateTime and arrivalDateTime.  If you really need a column with just the date, call it departureDate.  The lines under the word Date in your IDE are telling you that you can't use that word as a column name.